# Erro " Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY' "

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados

Bom galera to com o seguinte problema , ao inserir os dados em uma tabela eu automaticamente insiro os mesmo dados em outras duas tabelas , mas so da certo no primeiro linha que eu insiro , quando eu insiro outro linha aparece o seguinte erro :

Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'

Usando o seguinte código :

```
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO vendaproduto (id, id_venda, produtos)
SELECT venda.id_venda, venda.id_venda, venda.produtos
FROM venda")or die(mysql_error());

mysql_query("INSERT INTO vendaservico (id, id_venda, servicos)
SELECT venda.id_venda, venda.id_venda, venda.servicos
FROM venda")or die(mysql_error());
```

Então eu tentei assim :

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO vendaproduto (id_venda, produtos)
      SELECT venda.id_venda, venda.produtos
      FROM venda")or die(mysql_error());

mysql_query("INSERT INTO vendaservico (id_venda, servicos)
      SELECT venda.id_venda, venda.servicos
      FROM venda")or die(mysql_error());
```

so que a cada vez que eu insiro os dados na tabela ela duplica os dados , alguém sabe aonde eu estou errando ou pode me da uma ajuda , obg.

Codigo Inteiro :

```
if(isset($_POST['send'])){
    $venda = $_POST['num_venda'];
    $data = $_POST['data_venda'];
    $placa = $_POST['placa'];
    $km = $_POST['km'];
    $produtos = $_POST['produtos'];
    $servicos = $_POST['servicos'];


    include ('banco.php');


    mysql_query("INSERT INTO venda(id_venda, num_venda, data_venda, placa, km, produtos, servicos)
            values(
                NULL,
                '{$venda}',
                '{$data}',
                '{$placa}',
                '{$km}',
                '{$produtos}',
                '{$servicos}'

                            )
            ");


    header("location:lista.php");

}


mysql_query("INSERT INTO vendaproduto (id, id_venda, produtos)
          SELECT venda.id_venda, venda.id_venda, venda.produtos
          FROM venda");

mysql_query("INSERT INTO vendaservico (id, id_venda, servicos)
          SELECT venda.id_venda, venda.id_venda, venda.servicos
          FROM venda") ;

?>
```

Comment: Está com `AUTO_INCREMENT`?

Comment: Sim , esta como **AUTO_INCREMENT**

Comment: Mostra a estrutura destas tabelas para gente ver se tem algo errado.

Comment: A estrutura da tabela é que é importante. Qual é a diferença entre o `id` e o `id__venda`?

Comment: Esse `header` está fora de ordem. Depois que ele fizer o `INSERT` na tabela `VENDA` vai redirecionar pra essa página sem executar os `INSERTS` abaixo. Além disso, nesse primeiro `INSERT` está a coluna `id_venda`. É uma `PK` com `AUTO_INCREMENT` ? Se sim, não precisa colocar no `INSERT` como falei na minha resposta.

Comment: obg, vou arrumar o codigo aqui e ver no que vai da

Comment: Esse erro significa que você está tentando inserir um novo registro com mesma ID que está gravada com `auto_increment`.

Comment: Provavelmente `vendaproduto` e `vendaservico` já tenha o registro gravado e por isso vai dá erro... você não está verificando se já foi gravado... além disso, vc deve estar com regras nesse banco, por isso ele não aceita mais de uma chave estrangeira.

Comment: Dá uma lida aqui, extremamente recomendável para você: [Por que não devemos usar funções do tipo mysql_*?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/579/por-que-n%C3%A3o-devemos-usar-fun%C3%A7%C3%B5es-do-tipo-mysql)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se a coluna da chave primária estiver com auto incremento, você não precisa colocar ela no `INSERT`. Zera sua tabela e faça os testes de novo.

Comenta um `INSERT` e roda a página. Depois comenta o outro `INSERT` e roda a página. Veja se duplica.

Ah, e poste o `PHP` do seu código também. As vezes pode ter algo antes que esteja ocasionando isso, tipo um `while` ou `for`.

Comment: Então Zoom ele fez isto, ó problema é que isto esta duplicando os dados.

Comment: Postei o Codigo todo , e agora vou tentar alterar minha tabela para ver se da certo