# erro - SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicata du champ '0' pour la clef 'PRIMARY'

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, pdo

estou trabalhando em cima do meu tcc no qual crio um banco de dados de fornecedores para uma empresa de medicamentos.

Resumindo meu problema, na hora de enviar os dados para o meu banco de dados esta dando a mensagem de erro '**'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicata du champ '0' pour la clef 'PRIMARY''**'

Faz alguns dias que estou parado nesse problema , alguém poderia me ajudar?

```
    <?php
    $anunciopalavraChave = strip_tags(trim($_POST['palavra_chave']));
    $anuncionomeEmpresa = strip_tags(trim($_POST['nome_empresa']));
    $anuncioTelefone = strip_tags(trim($_POST['telefone']));
    $anuncioEstado = strip_tags(trim($_POST['estados']));
    $anuncioCidade = strip_tags(trim($_POST['cidades']));
    $anuncioSite = strip_tags(trim($_POST['site']));
    $anuncioEmail = strip_tags(trim($_POST['email']));      

    $anuncioCadatro = date('Y-m-d H:m:s');
    $anuncioTermino = date('Y-m-d H:m:s',strtotime('+1 month'));
    $anuncioStatus = 'pendente';

    $anuncioThumb = $_FILES['img'];
    $anuncioPasta = 'midias/';
    $imgPermitido = array('image/jpg','image/jpeg','image/pjpg');
    $contarImg = count($anuncioThumb['name']);
    require("admin/sistema/upload.php");

    for($i=0;$i<$contarImg;$i++){

        $imagemNome = $anuncioThumb['name'][$i];
        $imagemCaminho  = $anuncioThumb['tmp_name'][$i];
        $imagemTipo = $anuncioThumb['type'][$i];

        if(!empty($imagemNome) && in_array($imagemTipo, $imgPermitido)){
            $nome = 'cliente='.$clienteID.'-'.md5(uniqid(rand(), true)).'.jpg';
            Redimensionar($imagemCaminho, $nome, 130, $anuncioPasta);

            $sql_cadastraAnuncio = 'INSERT INTO fj_cadastroanuncio (vendasId, anunciopalavraChave, anuncionomeEmpresa, anuncioTelefone, anuncioEstado, anuncioCidade, anuncioSite,
                                     anuncioEmail, anuncioThumb, anuncioCadastro, anuncioTermino, anuncioStatus)';
            $sql_cadastraAnuncio .= 'VALUES (:vendasId, :anunciopalavraChave, :anuncionomeEmpresa, :anuncioTelefone, :anuncioEstado, :anuncioCidade, :anuncioSite,
                                     :anuncioEmail, :anuncioThumb, :anuncioCadastro, :anuncioTermino, :anuncioStatus)';

            try{
                $query_cadastraAnuncio = $conecta->prepare($sql_cadastraAnuncio);
                $query_cadastraAnuncio->bindValue(':vendasId',$clienteID,PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $query_cadastraAnuncio->bindValue(':anunciopalavraChave',$anunciopalavraChave,PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $query_cadastraAnuncio->bindValue(':anuncionomeEmpresa',$anuncionomeEmpresa,PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $query_cadastraAnuncio->bindValue(':anuncioTelefone',$anuncioTelefone,PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $query_cadastraAnuncio->bindValue(':anuncioEstado',$anuncioEstado,PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $query_cadastraAnuncio->bindValue(':anuncioCidade',$anuncioCidade,PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $query_cadastraAnuncio->bindValue(':anuncioSite',$anuncioSite,PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $query_cadastraAnuncio->bindValue(':anuncioEmail',$anuncioEmail,PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $query_cadastraAnuncio->bindValue(':anuncioThumb',$nome,PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $query_cadastraAnuncio->bindValue(':anuncioCadastro',$anuncioCadatro,PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $query_cadastraAnuncio->bindValue(':anuncioTermino',$anuncioTermino,PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $query_cadastraAnuncio->bindValue(':anuncioStatus',$anuncioStatus,PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $query_cadastraAnuncio->execute();

                echo '!!cadatro com sucesso!!!'; 

                }catch(PDOexception $error_cadastraAnuncio){
                    echo 'Erro ao cadastrar'.$error_cadastraAnuncio->getMessage();
                    }
            }

    }       
?>
```

Comment: Esse campo está autoincrement?

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/103706/erro-duplicate-entry-1-for-key-primary

Comment: rray , a sua pergunta me fez achar a reposta, o conflito estava no campo que estava autoincrement com a chave primária, obrigado !!!  obrigado também, Bacco!

Comment: @RaphaelBassanino posso fechar como duplicata daquela? Assim ajuda outras pessoas tambem.

Comment: ok, sem problemas @Bacco !

Comment: Feito. Assim, quem localizar a sua vai ter o link para aquela que já tem resposta.